# Cumulative count of non-empty cells that aren't contiguos

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I want to write a formula that gives the cumulative count of non-empty cells that aren't contiguous. Like an index count column for lack of a better term.

| A - Count | B - mix of empty and non-empty cells in this column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | some text |
| 2 | more text |
| (these cells don't have a number...) |  |
| (...because the cells on the right are empty) |  |
| 3 | text continues and so does count on the left |
| 4 | still counting only non-empty cells in this column |
| 5 | result is an index count column on the left |

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly. Are you asking about [**=COUNTA**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.2/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060181.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3149729)($B$2:$B7)?

Comment: @JohnSUN no, the formula you suggest gives [the result in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4xvv.png) what I am asking about is a formula that gives the result like in the table of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [**IF()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.2/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060105.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3150141) function to check if the adjacent cell is empty. If so, then leave the current cell empty. Otherwise, put the value of the counter increased by one in the cell. To find out the value of the counter, use the [**MAX()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.2/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060184.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3154511) function for all cells above the current one, or count all non-blank cells in column B from the first row to the current one using the [**COUNTA()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.2/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060181.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3149729) function

Enter the formula
`=IF(B2="";"";MAX($A$1:$A1)+1)`
or
`=IF(B2="";"";COUNTA($B$2:$B2))`
in cell **A2** and drag it down

The address of the last cell will change:

```
=IF(B3="";"";MAX($A$1:$A2)+1)       =IF(B3="";"";COUNTA($B$2:$B3))
=IF(B4="";"";MAX($A$1:$A3)+1)       =IF(B4="";"";COUNTA($B$2:$B4))
=IF(B5="";"";MAX($A$1:$A4)+1)       =IF(B5="";"";COUNTA($B$2:$B5))
=IF(B6="";"";MAX($A$1:$A5)+1)       =IF(B6="";"";COUNTA($B$2:$B6))
=IF(B7="";"";MAX($A$1:$A6)+1)       =IF(B7="";"";COUNTA($B$2:$B7))
```

[image: Result]